# Error when read excel from Microsoft.Office.Interrop.Excel

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

i use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to read Excel Here is my code:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo oldCI = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ko-KR");
Excel.Application eApp = new Excel.Application()
Excel.WorkBook oBooks = eApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName)
```

When it run to Open file Name it show error Old format or invalid type library.

> (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80028018 (TYPE_E_INVDATAREAD)).How I can fix it. It is a region in Korea and I cant change to en-US

Comment: Can you open the same file in excel itself? Excel has an odd behavior deciding on format checking the extension rather than content.

Comment: in korea region url of file with \ -> W and i think library can't understand this url